# Query for Merge values from 3 column and merge as Primary Key in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In one table few columns are there and in 3 columns i want to merge values from these 3 columns and generate as Primary key after merging these 3 values. 
**Col1** having Datatype **length 4**, While **col2** & **col3** having datatype **length 5** & **3** respectively. In **col2** & **col3** if any values are less than the maximum length then use **LPAD** with **0** and then after Merge into the Primary Key.

Ex- If **col1 = 1234, col2 = 142, col3 = 32** then after merging It should be like **"123400142032"** as **Primary Key**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
(
   col1   NUMBER,
   col2   NUMBER,
   col3   NUMBER
);

    ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD (ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( LPAD(col1,4,0)||LPAD(col2,5,0)||LPAD(col3,3,0) ) );
    ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT t_test_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX;
```

You may then insert only 3 columns and the column id gets automatically populated with a number such as `123400142032`.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (col1, col2, col3)
     VALUES (1234, 142, 32);
```

**Note** : The create table script is just for understanding. You may not need it since you already have an existing table.

The virtual column syntax `GENERATED .. AS` works only in 11g and above. For lower versions, you may require a before insert trigger and a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
with lp as 
(select max(length(employee_id)) mp from employee),

llp as
(select max(length(first_name)) mf from employee)

select lp.*,lpad(employee_id,lp.mp,'0'),llp.*, lpad(first_name,llp.mf,'0'),
employee_id||lpad(employee_id,lp.mp,'0')||lpad(first_name,llp.mf,'0')from lp,llp,employee;
```

note: here employee_id and first_name are the columns, you can assume it as column1 and column2..